# In FMX how to get the current URL of a TWebBrowser control?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser

I use Delphi 10.3 Community edition. My FireMonkey Android/iOS application has a tab with TWebBrowser control, so users can load and browse the sites from the bookmarked list. When a user clicks on any link (for example, a category, a new product item or a new site) in the already loaded site, the new link is also loaded into the TWebBrowser. How to programmatically determine this new link that the user have just clicked on? Or how to programmatically determine the link of the currently loaded document in the TWebBrowser? That is easy to do for Windows applications, but for mobile applications the TWebBrowser component has very limited functionality. For example:

1. I load first url to TWebBrowser:

   WebBrowser1.URL := 'site.com'
2. I browse this site and click on a new link site.com/category1 to see category1 page in the same TWebBrowser.
3. After that I try to get current  WebBrowser1 document url like this:

   Label1.Caption := WebBrowser1.URL

   but Label1.Caption is equal site.com, although it should be site.com/category1.

To define a new URL, I used different events like **OnDidFinishLoad** (starts many times), **OnDidStartLoad** (starts many times), **OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest** (never started) end even **TButton.Onclick** after new link is loaded. But I still couldn’t programmatically get the link site.com/category1.

Comment: I tried OnDidStartLoad and was able to get the URL for every link clicked on the web page. It does fire several times, but that shouldn't be a problem.
s:=(ASender as TWebBrowser).URL;

Comment: @DougRudd, it works in windows, but not works in android app. This simple code always ads to memo only the first start link: procedure TfMain.WebBrowser1DidFinishLoad(ASender: TObject);
var s: string;
begin
  s := (ASender as TWebBrowser).URL;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
end;

Comment: And OnDidStartLoad also returns the same result => first URL of the TWebBrowser component.